# How to authorize GAS web app to act on behalf of a user?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, web-applications, google-oauth, telegram-bot

So I've spent last couple of months to create an Editor add-on and get it verified. It is now published as "Unlisted", however, I can't get some crucial elements to work. Hopefully somebody can help to solve this.

## Current situation

In short, my add-on has a Web App deployment used to integrate with Telegram bot. It is presumed that whatever information user sends to a bot, then gets processed and reflected in a spreadsheet in some way.

It was working flawlessly in a contained version of a script before I decided to make it into a stand-alone add-on; however, now it won't really work when other users try to use it. I presume that is because my Web App is executed as "Me" (script owner), and "me" doesn't have access to the end users' spreadsheets (as it should be). So, the integration works nice until it's time to perform `SpreadsheetApp.openById(sheetId)` - then it falls with an error:

```
Exception: You do not have permission to access the requested document.
```

## Solutions that don't work for me

- **Asking a user to share the sheet**: I plan to open this script for a free usage at some point. I would like to preserve the users' privacy. It doesn't feel right to ask them to share their spreadsheets with me; however, perhaps if I could make it work from a service account, this request could be acceptable.
- **Execute as "User accessing the web app"**: Doesn't work because Telegram has anonymous access to the Web App. While the only way to provide anonymous access is to use "Access as me" instead of "Access as user".

## Possible solution

For the app's development I use `clasp` - a tool that helps to integrate local IDE with GAS. And this tool required authorization, which it requests by generating a link like this:

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?access_type=offline&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fscript.deployments%20https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fscript.projects%20https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fscript.webapp.deploy%20https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fdrive.metadata.readonly%20https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fdrive.file%20https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fservice.management%20https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Flogging.read%20https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.email%20https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.profile%20https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fcloud-platform&response_type=code&client_id=XXXXXXXXXXXX&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A54470
```

By following this link, I end up on the oAuth screen, where I choose my account and give access to this app to act on my behalf. I believe it uses the ID from the [Credentials](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials) screen, and I figured if I could generate a link like this for my Web App and give it to a used to perform authorization, then the system could work.

Now, it's only a matter of understanding how to create such a link, what ID to use, and how to make sure that my Web App is launched with the authorization provided.

Perhaps there are other solutions too? Service account? I'm very open to ideas.

PS: I know this has been answered in one way or another; but I was unable to find a case that would explain how to achieve the result in my setup (which is pure GAS, web app and a Telegram bot hooked up to it). Being a beginner developer, I was unable to fit those recommendations to my case. I would appreciate any advise!

Comment: Ask them to share the sheet? Or change to execute as "User accessing" instead of "Me"

Comment: @TheMaster Thanks - I was about to add this information but forgot. Unfortunately those solutions don't work for me; added the reason above.

Comment: Service account is just an another email address. Yes, you can access the sheet through service account credentials, but you need to use 1. Sheets API(direct methods like `openById` won't work) through `UrlFetchApp` and 2. Oauth: https://github.com/googleworkspace/apps-script-oauth2/blob/main/samples/GoogleServiceAccount.gs

Comment: @TheMaster Thanks for the recommendation. However, as I understood it, it only works for Workspace add-ons? This won't work here then, because mine is an Editor add-on.

Comment: I believe it works for both types.

Comment: @TheMaster Thanks! Bear with me please - I think we might be on to something.
As they say in Readme:

> If you are trying to connect to a Google API from Apps Script you might not need to use this library at all. Apps Script has a number of easy-to-use, built-in services, as well as a variety of advanced services that wrap existing Google REST APIs.

That seems to be my case. Here's the example I found:
https://github.com/googleworkspace/apps-script-oauth2/blob/main/samples/NoLibrary/Code.gs

Comment: So, it looks like ScriptApp.getOAuthToken(); is how I get access token; so I need to have my users launch this and store the result in properties. That can be arranged.

What I don't get yet, is how do I use this token then? All of my bot's logic is stored in doPost(e) function. How would I then use the token I've acquired earlier to authorize the bot?

Sorry for these weird questions. This Apps Script thing is really foreign to me, but I'm trying to learn.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256278/discussion-between-basil-vlasyuk-and-themaster).

Comment: `decided to make it into a stand-alone add-on;` How exactly did you make it a standalone add-on?

Comment: @TheMaster I created a separate standalone script, copy&pasted the code there, and changed it a bit so it could work with different spreadsheet instead of just one. Then I got it verified and published. It can now be installed by other users, but alas, doesn't work properly for them.

Comment: Ok, why do you want to open a different spreadsheet than the one attached? (I don't think you realize that editor addons are bound to the sheet that the user installs the addon in. So, you can just use `SpreadsheetApp.getActive()`. Have you reviewed add on Authorization life cycle in the documentation? )

Comment: I did. As I understand it, every user of an add-on has their own attached spreadsheet. So, getActive() will only work if Google knows who's asking. And it doesn't if the user addressing Web App is anonymous (which is the case, for now, with my Telegram bot).

For that reason openById() worked when I was the only one using the add-on, although getActive() would likely work just the same since WebApp is launched as "Me". But once I change it to launch as "User", the whole thing stops working, no matter if it's getActive() or openById(), because Web App user (the bot) is not authorized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Service account flow:

You can provide a menu asking for authorization, which when done, would share the current sheet to your service account's email. You can then use the service account credentials to access the sheet through sheets api. Do take special care to avoid leaking of the credentials.

###### Samples:

- https://github.com/googleworkspace/apps-script-oauth2/blob/main/samples/GoogleServiceAccount.gs
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/63655160/
- [Create service account](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-accounts-create#creating)

#### Access token storing:

Access tokens  will expire every hour, but you can use installed triggers [to store the token retrieved from `ScriptApp.getOAuthToken` to script properties](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52787692). This can then be retrieved from anonymous web app executions, as they share script properties. However, I believe this opens up multiple attack scenarios and I wouldn't recommend this from a security perspective.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, @TheMaster.
I am still convinced however that Domain-wide delegation is not available in my case. The very first action point in the manual says to use "Google Workspace domain's Admin console" which I don't even have access to. I control my project via console.cloud.google.com; I can create a service account, but I don't have the option to authorize it as any other account. Sorry if I misinterpreted your recommendation.

As for the token storing strategy, I'm afraid it won't work for me either because of the tokens' short lifespan.

Comment: @BasilVlasyuk 1. Domain wide delegation and impersonation is not needed. Just spreadsheet sharing. 2. I did address the short lifespan in the answer. Did you click the links?

Comment: Allow me more time to dig into this to make sure I understood your recommendations right. I'll be back.

Comment: All right, so for the access token: I've studied the suggested solution. Surely I didn't see it coming :D "Token dies every hour? Well just refresh it every hour with a timed trigger". I mean unironically, I haven't thought about it. I guess that's the exact reason why Google limited the amount of timed triggers a script can have on each document to just 1. And unfortunately I already have time-based trigger in use in my project. Even if I were to write a function that would swap my trigger with this one, that means the token refreshing one would skip an hour. Sub-optimal.

Comment: Now for the service account... By this time I have a more or less clear picture of how I could approach this one, one thing I'm still missing is how do I make it so doPost() function would run on behalf of the service account. I've read the items you suggested several times through, but it seems I just lack the knowledge to tie it together. From where I stand now, it seems that I have to create a service account (done), install apps-script-oauth2 library, create a getService_() and run() functions like in your first reference, and use run() at the beginning of my doPost(). Is that correct?

Comment: Continuing the previous comment... Would that also mean that I can't use any of the regular SpreadSheetApp functions, like you mentioned earlier, and should instead work via Sheet API? If I have an API Executable deployment, can I use my own functions?

Comment: 1. Yes, `run()` at `doPost`. You won't be able to use inbuilt functions. Everything goes through `UrlFetchApp` and Sheets API. 2.  Why do you need to swap the trigger? You can do multiple things in the same trigger. Do what the trigger already does and add code to add access token to props.

Comment: thanks - that's another prime idea I didn't think of. I'll have to see which one of these suits me best, and I'll let you know which one I will end up using.

Comment: Hi @TheMaster, I've decided to follow the "Store token" route for now. The only problem is, I need to execute my functions, not the standard ones from Spreadsheets API. I've read somewhere that it can be achieved through utilizing Executable deployment by fetching https://script.googleapis.com/v1/scripts/ID:run with the appropriate parameters; I'm trying that now, but the problem is I don't receive any return value. The function I run this way doesn't seem to have any effect either. Would you happen to have any advise on that? Appreciate your help.

Comment: Scratch that. I just forgot to deploy :D The return value is now received in "Result" field. I only now have to check if the whole system with automatic token refreshment will work - if so, I will accept this answer. Thanks again.

Comment: thank you for your help. I am accepting your answer - "Access token storing" tactic combined with API Executable deployment to run my own functions works flawlessly. If a bit slow, but I imagine that's not something anyone can influence.