# Editing a Google sheet by script with READ ONLY Grant

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, readonly

I need to write a Google script with the doGet() function that edits more cells of a Google sheet. This script is called via https URL. All the members of my Organization Will be able to call this URL and to edit in this way the cells of the sheet.
BUT I Need that the sheet itself isn't directly accessible to the members. They can modify the Google sheet ONLY by calling the doGet via https URL.

The question: how can I let the script function) called by the members to edit but also to prevent any editing by hand by the users?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77659451/how-to-authorize-gas-web-app-to-act-on-behalf-of-a-us

Answer (score 0):

2 methods to achieve this:

**1.Share sheet as "view only" and execute script as yourself**

First, share a spreadsheet to the whole company with the "Viewer" if you want them to be able to see, but not modify it. If you don't want them to see it at all, just don't share it.
Then, in AppsScript, when you deploy doGet() as a web app, you can set "Execute as" to "Me", and "Who has access" to your whole organization. This should be enough. [image]

**2. Protect ranges and unprotect them while the script is running**

If for some reason you can't execute as yourself, you can protect all of the sheet's ranges by default and use [Protection](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/protection) class in AppsScript to unlock certain ranges for other users just for the duration of the running script. Please see the examples in [Protection](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/protection) docs.

Comment: In my script I get also the session email. In this case, with your setup, I will get my email ore the one of the user that opens the URL of the script? (at the moment I've not a PC near to me for a couple of days, sorry)

Comment: Unfortunately yes, you will get your email. In this case, the only solution I have is to have all of the sheet's ranges protected against edits from your colleagues, and use [Protection](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/protection) class to give them editing rights just for the duration of the script.

Comment: Maybe... Could I create a "service" sheet (with edit grant to all) that have "Execute as..." set to the user that executes, and this sheet Will have a doGet that only calls my "real" sheet (that has not edit grants), passing it the session email of the colleague...? Because I'm afraid that if I use Protection on the fly, if an error occurs, the user will be granted to edit forever.

Comment: I think you could try it, it may be a good workaround.

Comment: The session email Is the One of the user, not mine..very well!